# How can I replay sessions with a delay between replays?

Tags: fiddler

I have 4 sessions captured with Fiddler. I want to automatically replay these sessions every half hour. I apologize for the broad question, but is there a way to accomplish this through scripting? I'm not sure which function(s) should look at editing.
Thanks.